# Haskell Function - Largest

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

So I am suppose to write a function called Largest in Haskell which finds the largest element of a list, but is implemented using the high order functions.

I am new to Haskell so this is my attempt which it doesnt work

```
largest :: [Int] -> Int
largest [] = 0
largest (head : tail) = if (head > tail) then head
else (largest tail)
```

I have no idea what does high order function mean.

some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To fix your attempt:

```
largest :: [Int] -> Int
largest [] = 0
largest (head : tail) = max head (largest tail)
```

Note that this will work only for non-negative numbers (you can fix this either by deciding that empty lists have no maximum - like Prelude's `maximum`, or by using the `minBound` for `Int` instead of `0`, but this wouldn't work e.g. for `Integer`).

However, this still doesn't use a higher order function. A suitable function for this kind of problem would be `foldl` (or better `Data.List.foldl'`) or `foldr`, but I don't want to spoil the fun.

Answer (score 2):

A higher order function takes one or more functions as one of its arguments, or returns a function. In this case, I assume the higher order argument should be a comparison function. This gives a simple definition for largest:

```
largest :: [a] -> (a -> a -> Ordering) -> a
largest (x:xs) cmp = go x xs
    where go largest []     = largest
          go largest (x:xs) = case cmp largest x of
             LT -> go x xs
             _  -> go largest xs
```

also, just to let you know, there is a function to do this for you in the Prelude called `maximum`. `maximum [2,3,4,1] == 4`

Answer (score 1):

To complete existing answers,

The first problem you have to overcome is to try to compile your code, or at least to understand the error message. This hint should give you great guidance about the issue you are facing and how to modify it in order to have a correct version (even if you don't fill the high-order function requirement, at least you will have a working one).

For this, let's take a look at type signature of the pattern clause, **(head : tail)**,

First for the (:) function, we have,

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Then we deduce the following type for **head** and **tail**, (which are the argument's of (:)),

- head is of type Int.
- tail is of type [Int].

Again, let's take a look at type signature of (>)

```
(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

If we omit the constraint class, to keep it simple, we have,

```
(>) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

Or in your code there is,

```
....
if ( head > tail) ...
....
```

Which can be rewrite, again to simplify,  as

```
....
if ((>) head tail)) ...
....
```

Using all the previous remarks you should be able to rebuilt the type provided to the (>) function and understand the issue.

Then you can correct your code and **make it works**.
After you could take a look at [high order function](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~en1000/haskell/hof.html), and then **make it right**.

As a general remark, When you are stuck on a complex problem try to break it down into smaller one, and for each sub-problem try to apply the following cooking principle.

> Make it works,
>   Make it right,
>   Make if fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (head > tail)
```

First, you don't need the brackets. Second, and more serious, `head` is an integer, but `tail` is a *list of integers*. You cannot compare these two things.

```
largest (head : tail) = if (head > tail) then head
else largest tail
```

This is not correctly indented. The `else` must be indented at least as far as the `if`. You can either put the `then` and the `else` on the same line, or do something like

```
if head > tail
  then head
  else largest tail
```

(Again, you don't actually need the brackets - although they don't hurt anything.)

As a final note, there is a predefined function called `head`, and one called `tail`, so these aren't the best choice of variable names. The idiomatic Haskell choice is `x` and `xs` (plural of "x"). You will see a lot of code written like this. It also helps to remind you that `x` is a thing and `xs` is a list of things.

Comment: http://ideone.com/3veT8I shows `else` undented to the left of `if`, but it works OK.